# Xcode Bot CI | Unable to find matching destination

Tags: ios, xcode, git, continuous-integration, xcode-bots

I have setup an Xcode server and using Xcode Bots to do CI in my machine. (Same is used for development.)

Creating a bot for a project, works fine. However, if I add the same project to the workspace, (I have shared the scheme - [which is set to the workspace container] so that is not the issue.) I am getting the below error.

> xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided
>   destination specifier:

The git currently resides on the Xcode server. 
(Followed the steps [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH8-SW1))

**Also noticed that, once I clone the repository and open the .xcworkspace, the project and the scheme is not displayed.**

I suspect this to be the issue. However, not able to find a way to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[Using Xcode version: 7.3.1 on OS X El Capitan v: 10.11.4]